# How would I make one component have a fullscreen background image?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, debugging

I would to set a background just for this component below and no where else.  In other words, upon the user clicking `Login` or `Sign Up`, the next page that it goes to shouldn't have the background image that should only belong to this `LoginSignUpContainer`.

I've looked around the web and SO and still couldn't find a silver bullet solution to this.  I understand React.js is designed for SPAs (Single Page Apps) but I'm sure it's still possible.

My attempt below, along with many other attempts, haven't done me any justice.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's my js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Login from './Login/Login';
import SignUp from './SignUp/SignUp';
import './LoginSignUpContainer.css';

class LoginSignUpContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            login: true,
            signUp: false
        };
        this.switchTabs = this.switchTabs.bind(this);
    }

    switchTabs(word) {
        let login, signUp;

        if(word === "Sign Up") {
            login = false;
            signUp = true;
        } else {
            login = true;
            signUp = false;
        }

        this.setState({login: login, signUp: signUp});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="back col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <p id="login" onClick={this.switchTabs.bind(null, "Sign Up")}>Sign Up</p>
                <p id="login" onClick={this.switchTabs.bind(null, "Login")}>Login</p>

                {this.state.signUp ? <SignUp/> : null}
                {this.state.login ? <Login/> : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginSignUpContainer;
```

Here's css code:

```
.back {
    background-image: url("../path/picture.png");
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: is your problem that the background appears in "SignUp" and "Login" components?

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not see your result on the screen, I am not 100% sure how it is displayed.

But try the below style changes and see,

```
.back {
    background-image: url("../path/picture.png");
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: ah, I tried that exact code before but it didn't work.  I've attached a screenshot of what it looks like!

Comment: I believe, your parent component isn't full width and height.. you need to check ur parent component HTML.